# Is it possible to force Xamarin Studio to update list of provisioning profiles in command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, continuous-integration, xamarin-studio

I have a continuous integration build server setup which builds Xamarin projects. It connects to a Mac build host which has Xamarin studio installed, and configured with my Apple dev account credentials.

If I add a new provisioning profile, or modify an existing one, I know I can get Xamarin to update it's list by going into options->Developer Account and hitting refresh.

However that won't fly for my CI server. Can I do the same from the command line somehow?

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible to do in Xamarin Studio, but I've added the Xcode tag in case someone knowledgeable with Xcode knows of a way to get Xcode to fetch them from the command-line (which Xamarin Studio would be able to use).

Comment: @jstedfast, Xamarin Studio does it through the GUI, do you know what it's actually doing? Is it calling on xcode somehow? If I know what's going on behind the scenes maybe I can find out more info and do this myself..